# How to create a class with a math function that is defined at run time?

Tags: c++, string, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any kind of “expression class” (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978247/is-there-any-kind-of-expression-class-c)

I want to make a class that holds a function that is defined at run time.
i.e.

```
function function1("x*sin(3.141*x)");
```

I want to do things like find roots and it would be better not having to rewrite the program each time.

edit: I am looking at lua.

Comment: Do you mean you want to evaluate a string containing a C++ expression? Your question isn't really clear at the moment...

Comment: Depending on what you're actually asking, you might be interested in [muParser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/).

Comment: Yes I want to take a string from the user and store it in a class and then use it like a math expression. What is unclear so I can correct it?

Comment: Why do you want to use C++ for this? This kind of thing is very simple in dynamic languages, e.g. in Python it's just `eval`. It's by nature much more cumbersome in static languages.

Comment: I mean a math function, function1 is an example of how I want to initialize a class named function as it is holding a math function.

Comment: @fork, C++ has no methods it has member functions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I want to use c++ as the function will be evaluated alot so I want the speed of a compiled language.

Comment: Well, then you need to compile it, otherwise you obviously _won't_ get this speed. You won't need to _build_ your entire program, just compile the file with your formula in it and link it to the program.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is certainly much easier in dynamic languages. For example, in Matlab you can evaluate strings using the `eval` command.

However, this is not impossible in C++. You might be able to make a nice solution with a combination of [C++11 lambdas](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) and a custom interpreter. The member function can take a lambda as an argument, and you can formulate the lambda by interpreting a string.

This answer might give you a good starting point for the interpreting part of the challenge.

[Evaluate Mathematical Function from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977045/evaluate-mathematical-function-from-string)